# angularjs NgTable ng-repeat groupby with show/hide

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters, ngtable

I can't get the 'groupBy' working.
I have a data set returned from a $http factory. The data is passed to the $scope 'territoryReq' variable.
the data set looks like:

```
[{"Country":"Netherlands","Name":"firstName lastName","Phone":"+12345678","Mobile":"+987654321"},{"Country":"Netherlands","Name":"firstName2 lastName2","Phone":"+12345678","Mobile":"+987654321"}]
```

I have a simple 'dump' of the data by using:

```
<div>
    <table ng-table="" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr class="ng-table-group" ng-repeat="entries in territoryReq">
            <td>
                {{entries.Country}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{entries.Name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{entries.Phone}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{entries.Mobile}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is all working. No problem.
Now I want to have the results grouped by Country. Preferably by being able to click on the country which then unhides the rows with the correct country.
I was looking at the example of [example of ng-table with grouping](https://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/ojvGaN/)

But I can't get it working for my data..
In the example they use e.g. `group in $groups` but I can't figure out where $groups come from?
Anyway, I hope someone can help me in the right direction...

thanks!

Comment: I just revised my previous answer which I know was incomplete. take a look now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For straight up grouping, `groupBy` takes an object property as the parameter. It should be as simple as

```
<tr class="ng-table-group" ng-repeat="entries in territoryReq | groupBy: 'Country'">
```

But it sounds more like you want to filter the list based on criteria, like country.

I mocked this up to demonstrate what I think you're looking for. Please take a look and see if it helps... It has ordering via the table headers and filtering from a dynamic list of countries.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-yvxdrd

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's a good start. The goal is to have the table with countries. Countries are "clickable" and will show the rows (e.g. Name and phone) of people belonging to that country. Other rows (from other countries) shall be hidden...

Comment: Isn't that what is happening in the demo i made? If you click on the country it will hide all other rows. I updated it to make the countries column clickable.

Comment: It is now working as expected! thank you for your support!!